# Logarithm on Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Data frame like this,

```
a  b  c  d  e
1  0  0  4  5
0  23 5  0  0
0  5  8  6  0
```

Now, i am using a `np.log` on the entire data frame like this.

```
df = (np.log(weights_df))
```

Its all fine and working out. But wherever there is 0, its giving "-inf" as it is supposed to. I want to convert all of these to something else, maybe "0" in place of "-inf". I tried `fillna` but i do not think its going to work here.

How do i do it?

Comment: You need to set `pd.set_option('use_inf_as_null', True)` for inf to be regarded as NaN. Then you can use `fillna` or `dropna` for inf values as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-np.inf` and `np.inf` are not considered null or na.

Use `replace(-np.inf, 0)`:

```
df = (np.log(weights_df)).replace(-np.inf, 0)

df
```

[image]